# Magento 2.3.x how to add custom field in PayPal express review Page?

Tags: magento2.3.4, paypal-express

Magento 2.3.x, How can we add custom fields in Paypal express review page for guest users and save the value in order and invoice?

For example:

Paypal express review page needs to add the Contact Number for the guest user. Next, we need to show the contact number in order view page, invoice, order, and invoice emails also.

any suggestions...

Coding structure is like below

1.Add Contact number in review.phtml file
frontend\templates\express\review.phtml

```
<div class="guestphone-paypalexpress">
  <strong class="box-title"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Phone Number')) ?></span></strong>
  <input type="text" name="guestphone-paypalexpress" id="phonenumber_paypalexpress" onkeypress='return restrictAlphabets(event)' required>
</div>
```

2.Add the events.xml
\app\code\Namespace\Modulename\etc\events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
   <event name="sales_order_place_after">
        <observer name="sales_order_place_after" instance="Diageo\PaypalPhone\Observer\SavePhoneNumber" />
    </event>
</config>
```

3.trying to get review.phtml form post data in observer file but its not getting.

\app\code\Namespace\Modulename\Observer\SavePhoneNumber.php

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SavePhoneNumber implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_request;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Status\HistoryFactory $historyFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory
    ) { 
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->_historyFactory = $historyFactory;
        $this->_orderFactory = $orderFactory;
    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        //$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $post = $this->_request->getParams();

        $logger->info('Params' . json_encode($post));
    }
}
```

i am not understand where i did a mistake.
Note:i have tried different events like sales_order_place_before,paypal_express_place_order_success but post date is not getting.

Comment: @CoderKube any solution?

Comment: I have used the exact same code that is provided in the question and it worked just fine for me. There was a minor mistake that you have used the name attribute 2 times with the field :) everything else workedfine.